# How to access json array in url that needs bearer token and display in android studio?

Tags: java, android, json

Hello stackoverflow community!!

How do I access a JSON array
in this URL "https://api.json-generator.com/templates/z0aMAeTBHKq3/data"

token is "2oof0bzpgllll2a8k2fmmh6aaykeu8yptztdzke7"

but when I display the data in an `Activity`, it just displays blank and exits the app. But When I change the URL without an auth/bearer token I can see the displayed data in the URL.

So my question: is how do I put the token in header so that I can have access and see the data displayed in the mobile phone?

I know it is simple but i am having a hard time.

**This is my *MainActivity.java***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private List<Movie> movieList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    requestQueue = VolleySingleton.getmInstance(this).getRequestQueue();

    movieList = new ArrayList<>();
    fetchMovies();

}


private void fetchMovies() {
    //Url with auth
    String url = "https://api.json-generator.com/templates/z0aMAeTBHKq3/data";

    //URL without auth
    //String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            for (int i = 0 ; i < response.length() ; i ++){
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    String userId = jsonObject.getString("userId");
                    String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                    String title = jsonObject.getString("title");
                    String body = jsonObject.getString("body");

                    Movie movie = new Movie(title , userId , id , body);
                    movieList.add(movie);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                MovieAdapter adapter = new MovieAdapter(MainActivity.this , movieList);

                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    HashMap headers = new HashMap();
    String authValue = "Bearer " + 
    "2oof0bzpgllll2a8k2fmmh6aaykeu8yptztdzke7";
    headers.put("Authorization", authValue);
    headers.put("Accept", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
}
```

**this is my *Movie.java***

```
public class Movie {

private String userId , id , title, body;


public Movie(String userId , String id , String title , String body){
    this.title = title;
    this.userId = userId;
    this.id = id;
    this.body = body;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getBody() {
    return body;
}
}
```

**this is my *MovieAdapter.java***

```
public class MovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.MovieHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<Movie> movieList;

public MovieAdapter(Context context , List<Movie> movies){
    this.context = context;
    movieList = movies;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public MovieHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item , parent , false);
    return new MovieHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MovieHolder holder, int position) {

    Movie movie = movieList.get(position);
    holder.userId.setText(movie.getUserId().toString());
    holder.id.setText(movie.getId());
    holder.title.setText(movie.getTitle());
    holder.body.setText(movie.getBody());


    holder.constraintLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context , DetailActivity.class);

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("userId" , movie.getUserId());
            bundle.putString("id" , movie.getId());
            bundle.putString("title" , movie.getTitle());
            bundle.putString("body" , movie.getBody());

            intent.putExtras(bundle);

            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return movieList.size();
}

public class MovieHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


    TextView title , userId , id, body;
    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;

    public MovieHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        userId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userid_tv);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_tv);
        id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_tv);
        body = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_tv);
        constraintLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    }
}
}
```

**This is my VolleySingleton.java**

```
public class VolleySingleton {

private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private static VolleySingleton mInstance;

private VolleySingleton(Context context){
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext());
}

public static synchronized VolleySingleton getmInstance(Context context){

    if (mInstance == null){
        mInstance = new VolleySingleton(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue(){return requestQueue;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This**

**Change**

```
private void fetchMovies() {
    //Url with auth
    String url = "https://api.json-generator.com/templates/z0aMAeTBHKq3/data";

    //URL without auth
    //String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            for (int i = 0 ; i < response.length() ; i ++){
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    String userId = jsonObject.getString("userId");
                    String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                    String title = jsonObject.getString("title");
                    String body = jsonObject.getString("body");

                    Movie movie = new Movie(title , userId , id , body);
                    movieList.add(movie);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                MovieAdapter adapter = new MovieAdapter(MainActivity.this , movieList);

                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    HashMap headers = new HashMap();
    String authValue = "Bearer " + 
    "2oof0bzpgllll2a8k2fmmh6aaykeu8yptztdzke7";
    headers.put("Authorization", authValue);
    headers.put("Accept", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

**To**

```
private void fetchMovies() {
//        Url with auth
        String url = "https://api.json-generator.com/templates/z0aMAeTBHKq3/data";

//        URL without auth
//        String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

          JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        for (int i = 0 ; i < response.length() ; i ++){
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                String userId = jsonObject.getString("userId");
                                String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                                String title = jsonObject.getString("title");
                                String body = jsonObject.getString("body");

                                Movie movie = new Movie(title , userId , id , body);
                                movieList.add(movie);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            MovieAdapter adapter = new MovieAdapter(MainActivity.this , movieList);

                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                String authValue = "Bearer " + "2oof0bzpgllll2a8k2fmmh6aaykeu8yptztdzke7";
                headers.put("Authorization", authValue);
                headers.put("Accept", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                return headers;
            }

        };
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
```

put your headers code inside `getHeaders() @Overtide` method